# How do I count different values of an attribute from an array of hashes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array of hashes called @messages :

```
[{ "id" => "1", "user_name" => "John", "content" => "xxxxx" },
 { "id" => "2", "user_name" => "John", "content" => "yyyyy" },
 { "id" => "3", "user_name" => "Paul", "content" => "zzzzzz" },
 { "id" => "4", "user_name" => "George", "content" => "xxyyzz" }]
```

What is the method to count the different values of `user_name` in @messages (which should give 3 here)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no method to do it, the simplest solution I can think of is using map:

```
attributes = [{ "id" => "1", "user_name" => "John", "content" => "xxxxx" },
   { "id" => "2", "user_name" => "John", "content" => "yyyyy" },
   { "id" => "3", "user_name" => "Paul", "content" => "zzzzzz" },
   { "id" => "4", "user_name" => "George", "content" => "xxyyzz" }]

count = attributes.map { |hash| hash['user_name'] }.uniq.size
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu already have your answer, but if you are also interested in the actual number per `user_name`, you could do

```
counts = attributes.inject(Hash.new{|h,k|h[k]=0}) { |counts, h| counts[h['user_name']] += 1 ; counts}
```

Then `counts.size` tells you how many distinct names there are.

Comment: yep, i had seen this way of solving. But hadn't gone further with `size`. Works as well!

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be using `group_by`:

```
attributes = [{ "id" => "1", "user_name" => "John", "content" => "xxxxx" },
   { "id" => "2", "user_name" => "John", "content" => "yyyyy" },
   { "id" => "3", "user_name" => "Paul", "content" => "zzzzzz" },
   { "id" => "4", "user_name" => "George", "content" => "xxyyzz" }]
attributes.group_by{|hash| hash["user_name"]}.count # => 3
```